# How many images do I need for fine-tunning the yolo_nas_l model?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolonas

So, I would like to fine-tune the Yolo-nas-l model for person classes.
The number of images of person class with annotations I have right now is 3979, 1135 valid, and 569 test.
I'm getting good map at 050-95 but bad precision and recall, so should I increase the train_set?
So any suggestions.

So for finetunning the model this were the training paras and I trained it for 100 epochs

```
train_params = {
    'silent_mode': False,
    "average_best_models": True,
    "warmup_mode": "LinearEpochLRWarmup",
    "warmup_initial_lr": 1e-6,
    "lr_warmup_epochs": 3,
    "initial_lr": 5e-4,
    "lr_mode": "cosine",
    "cosine_final_lr_ratio": 0.1,
    "optimizer": "Adam",
    "optimizer_params": {"weight_decay": 0.0001},
    "zero_weight_decay_on_bias_and_bn": True,
    "ema": True,
    "ema_params": {"decay": 0.9, "decay_type": "threshold"},
    "max_epochs": MAX_EPOCHS,
    "mixed_precision": True,
    "loss": PPYoloELoss(
        use_static_assigner=False,
        num_classes=len(dataset_params['classes']),
        reg_max=16
    ),
    "valid_metrics_list": [
        DetectionMetrics_050(
            score_thres=0.3,
            top_k_predictions=100,
            num_cls=len(dataset_params['classes']),
            normalize_targets=True,
            post_prediction_callback=PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback(
                score_threshold=0.01,
                nms_top_k=500,
                max_predictions=150,
                nms_threshold=0.7
            )
        ),
        DetectionMetrics_050_095(
            score_thres=0.3,
            top_k_predictions=100,
            num_cls=len(dataset_params['classes']),
            normalize_targets=True,
            post_prediction_callback=PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback(
                score_threshold=0.01,
                nms_top_k=500,
                max_predictions=150,
                nms_threshold=0.7
            )
        ),

    ],
    "metric_to_watch": 'mAP@0.50:0.95'
}
```

and this was the result after 100 epochs

```
Valid_PPYoloELoss/loss_cls: 0.8076702356338501  
Valid_PPYoloELoss/loss_iou: 0.329728901386261   
Valid_PPYoloELoss/loss_dfl: 0.44104906916618347 
Valid_PPYoloELoss/loss: 1.5784482955932617  
Valid_Precision@0.50: 0.48968252539634705   
Valid_Recall@0.50: 0.9280189275741577   
Valid_mAP@0.50: 0.8829154372215271  
Valid_F1@0.50: 0.6410865187644958   
Valid_Precision@0.50:0.95: 0.3704988658428192   
Valid_Recall@0.50:0.95: 0.7021487355232239  
Valid_mAP@0.50:0.95: 0.6309549808502197 
Valid_F1@0.50:0.95: 0.4850526750087738
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying additional data augmentation techniques to your existing dataset. This might include random rotations, flips, and changes in scale to make your model more robust. Use packages like [Albumentations](https://albumentations.ai/) for this